# Can we identify all “closure-confined” subsets?

Tags: general-topology

Forgive me if this is just me not knowing some preexisting name, but let's introduce the following notion:

**Definition** Let $U, X$ be topological spaces and $\iota\colon U\to X$ be an open embedding.
A subset $S\subseteq U$ is called *closure-confined with respect to $\iota$* if the closure of $\iota(S)$ in $X$ is contained in $\iota(U)$.

This is of course a useful notion when we're talking about the ring $C(X) := C(X, \mathbb R)$: If the nonzero-set of an $f\in C(U)$ is closure-confined with respect to the inclusion of $U\subseteq X$, f extends to an element of $C(X)$ by setting it to $0$ outside of $U$.

**Question** For any topological space $X$, can we identify the subsets which are closure-confined with respect to any open embedding?
What if we require the embeddings to map to Hausdorff spaces?

In the Hausdorff case, we at least know that all the relatively compact sets $R$ in $U$ are relatively confined, since $\iota(R)$ must always be compact and hence already closed.

Comment: In the case that the space admits a [Hausdorff compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_(mathematics)), then every non-relatively-compact set will not be closure confined w/r/t to the embedding into the compactification, as you can verify. The case where we don't have a Hausdorff compactification seems harder.